# java impersonation

Tags: java, windows, java-native-interface, impersonation

We have a java process running as the local system user on windows that needs to access a file that is owned by another user on the system. From what I understand the local system user should have permissions to impersonate that user. To do this we pass the tid and pid of a program that is accessing the file and get the user information (a token) from that. Then we set the token on the current thread. Something like this:

```
DuplicateTokenEx(hToken,MAXIMUM_ALLOWED,NULL,SecurityImpersonation,TokenImpersonation,&hTokenDup);
SetThreadToken(NULL, hTokenDup);
```

Where hToken is obtained by opening the thread and then process via their ids.
The problem is when I try to access a file that is only accesible by the user and no one else I am unable to read it. I get an access denied error. So the question is whether or not I should be able to access this file via impersonation and if so is this the correct to impersonate another user given a threadid and pid. I guess also would I see different behavior between windows 7 and windows xp.

Comment: My knowledge of Java is close to zero so bear with me if I'm saying nonsense but... my first ideas would be to 1) Run with other user 2) Alter the file permissions

Comment: We can't do that. We don't have that information beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you should **always** test the return values of your Windows API calls.
Only then will you be sure that the token has indeed been copied and assigned to your process.

Impersonation requires some privileges, which I'm not really not sure you'd have if you're a simple user. I suspect the DuplicateTokenEx function fails.
Try again with administrator privileges (use the "Run as..."  tool), and let us know how it goes.

Comment: Sorry I left some code out...we are checking the return values and everything is coming back ok. Also we are local system user which supposedly has the correct priveleges or at least has impersonation previlege.

Comment: If you really are running under the SYSTEM account, I don't think there are any files you can't read (or whose permissions you can't change).